# Error when Play file .mp3 (StorageFile ) with BackgroundMediaPlayer in isolated storage windows phone 8.1 rt

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I use  Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime 
I get my song  in isolated storage

My code :
storageFile is song in isolated storage

```
IRandomAccessStream stream = await storagefile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.SetStreamSource(stream);
BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.Play();
```

When I play it,but it not work  , like photo (try emulator and device lumina 520)

http://photoshare7.com/image/f5a

_message:
Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayer ' to type 'Windows.Media.Playback.IMediaPlayerSource'

Please Help me .Tks all.Sr my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into the same issue :) This happens when you call `SetStreamSource` from foreground application. See [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn642090.aspx]. To play audio from a file, you need to send background audio player a message (see [[How to pass an object to background project in Windows Phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25230225/how-to-pass-an-object-to-background-project-in-windows-phone])).

Comment: Tks For share 
I use Pass Path of StorageFile (My Song in device ) from ForeGround to Background with Mess (Wp8.1 RT)  and  it works.