# How to play Local MP3 file in BackgroundMediaPlayer in WIndows 10

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp

I am developing a simple MP3 player for windows 10. I am unable to play a local storagefile mp3. Even from KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.

I am successful in playing an MP3 file from project(appx).

I had tried many solutions, none of the worked for me.

Solutions tried:

1. [Error when Play file .mp3 (StorageFile ) with BackgroundMediaPlayer in isolated storage windows phone 8.1 rt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28360812/error-when-play-file-mp3-storagefile-with-backgroundmediaplayer-in-isolated)
2. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f2d7a760-a175-453f-9575-739b14f68136/open-file-from-music-library-in-backgroundmediaplayer-using-window-phone-81-xaml-c?forum=wpdevelop
3. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/a016edcf-d3d7-44e8-83e3-3a66d14ff301/why-not-play-songs-from-phone-music-library-on-device-in-wp81-wherein-music-plays-in-emulator?forum=wpdevelop
4. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn642090.aspx
5. [How to pass an object to background project in Windows Phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25230225/how-to-pass-an-object-to-background-project-in-windows-phone)

and many many more.

Comment: All the things you tried apply to Windows (Phone) 8(.1). You should take a look into the UWP example provided by Microsoft.

Comment: @Herdo, I had implemented https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples, I could only play files from te project mp3 files. Not from storagefile in musiclibrary.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I've tried every available method in the BackgroundMediaPlayer (including the new MediaPlaylist) and nothing seems to be able to play a local file.  Web url's, embedded files are fine...